# CSS margin inside table

Tags: css, margin

I'm trying with no luck apply right margins inside tables

```
<html>
  <style>
    input,select {
      width: 100%;
      margin-right: 15px;
      background: red;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <table border="2" color="red" width="100%">
       <tr>
         <td width="25%"><input type="text" /></td>
         <td width="25%"><select><option>foobar</option></select></td>
         <td width="25%"><input type="text" /></td>
         <td width="25%"><input type="text" /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
         <td width="25%"><input type="text" /></td>
         <td width="25%"><input type="text" /></td>
         <td width="25%"><select><option>foobar</option></select></td>
         <td width="25%"><input type="text" /></td>
       </tr>
    <table>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/3reat/

Only using CSS it's possible to define this margins 100% - 15px?

http://jsfiddle.net/3reat/2/

Comment: try css3 calc (e.g) margin: calc(100%-15px)

Comment: Where to you need to add margin/padding? From the table outside? Table inside? Cells? Be a bit more specific please.

Comment: @TamilSelvan thank you! Create a answer, than I will accept.

Comment: If `calc()` is ok for you, then use it in the right way, with spaces: `calc(100% - 15%)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try css3 calc

(e.g)

```
margin: calc(100% - 15px);
margin: -webkit-calc(100% - 15px);
margin: -moz-calc(100% - 15px);
```

Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/calc

Comment: Tamil - Need spaces `calc(100% - 15px)`

Comment: I tested in Google Chrome without spaces it's not working. Give a try